# About deleting fields in Odoo

Tags: python, orm, openerp-7, openerp-8

In OpenERP, the data model is described and manipulated through Python classes and objects. It is the ORM job to bridge the gap ... then for example when I add a field in _columns = { 'age': fields.integer('Age') } I'll find it in the database, but even if I delete it, it still are in the database. my question is, is it a method to delete if from the database too ? what do the developpers do with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

**Just you can try to check with update your OpenERP 7.0 server in below way.**

```
 ./openerp-server --addons-path=../addons/,../web/addons/ -u < your module name> -d < your database name >
```

then after you can check with your database table if it not remove this way 
you should follow this way as well.

```
 ./openerp-server --addons-path=../addons/,../web/addons/ -u all  -d < your database name>
```

If you are using Odoo 8.0 then just remove the `--addons-path` and then run the command from the terminal.

This way it may definitely solve your problem .

I hope my answer may help you :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, please can you explain more ? i did not understand the solution, i want to delete fields of the database from python class, not manually from postgres, for example in my specific module i worked with 4 fields nom, prénom, age, adresse ... but after i delete adresse from my python class, but it still are in the database.
And by the way, when i executed the command you proposed i got the error : bash: ./openerp-server: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Comment: i mean your database table does not update properly so that I will give to u for both the command to update the database table and all

Comment: please can you explain how can i execute the command, because that gave me error : bash: ./openerp-server: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Comment: please write this one "Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type " in english language so that I can easily understand

Comment: it means : No files or folders of this type
tell me the steps to execute this command, have i just open the terminal and paste it ?? that did not work for me

Comment: u must have to apply this command in your server directory then after you can check this one